# CPF8E2F - Lock on *SRVPGM object

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have a created a service program and it is invoked from COBOL, CL and RPGLE programs. I am running into the below issue at times and i am not sure of the reasons. I tried searching in Google and StackOverflow as well but found no solutions.

Please let me know the possible reasons for this issue.

```
                    Additional Message Information                         

Message ID . . . . . . :   CPF8E2F       Severity . . . . . . . :   30         
Message type . . . . . :   Diagnostic                                          
Date sent  . . . . . . :   11/10/16      Time sent  . . . . . . :   10:54:52   

Message . . . . :   Object ACB0500R is temporarily unavailable.                
Cause . . . . . :   A lock on object ACB0500R of type *SRVPGM in library       
  LMIQALIB is currently held by another job. The object is unavailable for use 
  at this time.                                                                
Recovery  . . . :   Try to access the object again.  If the object is still    
  locked, use the WRKOBJLCK command to determine which job holds the lock.
```

Comment: `...at times...`? At what times? When does it happen? What are you trying to do when it happens? Is anything else significant happening in the system, e.g., a backup?

Comment: @user2338816 I am not sure of the exact reason. However i am sure system backup or any updates were executing when i faced this issue. Multiple developers were working on the project and i probably assume that someone else would have been compiling it when i faced the issue. I am not sure of it though. I faced it twice on the same day and haven't seen the issue after that. I posted so that i can be sure it doesn't happen in production by any chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you do as instructed and use the WRKOBJLCK command to see what job had a lock on the *SRVPGM?

There's no locks done on a *SRVPGM object during normal execution.

The only time a *SRVPGM or *PGM object would be locked

1. Backup/Restore operation
2. Programmer intentionally adds a lock of the object (via ALCOBJ command or an API), to prevent multiple people from running the same program and the same time.
3. If the *SRVPGM/*PGM is currently being run in debug in another job (maybe?)
4. during creation (maybe?)

3 & 4 are educated guesses...I've never actually tried to watch for a lock during those processes..

What are you trying to do when you get the lock?  Execute or recreate?

Comment: I checked for object locks. Though there was an object lock it was released within moments. Is there a possibility to ALCOBJ on a service? Maybe someone from my team was debugging. I will keep on an eye for this issue and let you know on further details.

Comment: Debugging doesn't cause the service program to be locked. Creation or updsrvpgm could cause it to be locked.

Comment: @BarbaraMorris, I should know not to doubt you...but no lock even if for instance *LIST debug view is being used?  It'd seem to me there should be at least a temporary lock.  Or when a SEP is added...

Comment: @Charles, I had checked the *LIST scenario already by using WRKOBJLCK in the middle of the debug session. I just checked the SEP scenario, and WRKOBJLCK doesn't show a lock in that case either.